# Adding elements from a list in a nested list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11. I have a nested list -

```
nestedList = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

and another list -

```
newList = [1,2,3]
```

I need to club these and want a final list -

```
finalList = [[a, b, c, 1], [d, e, f, 2], [g, h, i, 3]]
```

Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: is there something you tried doing and failed?

Comment: If you want to update your list in place use `map(lambda (x, y): x.extend([y]),zip(nestedList, newList))
`

Comment: for your next question, you should create a ready-to-run example without `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]` ex with numbers or with quoted strings so everyone can use your input data without having to rework it. check my answer: it's self-contained.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you! Point noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just zip both lists together and create a new sublist:

```
nestedlist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newlist = [10,11,12]

result = [a+[x] for a,x in zip(nestedlist,newlist)]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6, 11], [7, 8, 9, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> nestedList = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
>>> newList = [1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> for num in range(len(newList)):
    nestedList[num].append(newList[num])    
>>> print nestedList
[['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For education purpose, a solution with recursion. Do not use in productive code.

```
nestedList = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

newList = [1,2,3]

def appendto(L1, L2):
  if L1 == []:
    return []
  else:
    return [L1[0] + [L2[0]]] + appendto(L1[1:], L2[1:])

print(appendto(nestedList, newList))
# -> [['a', 'b', 'c', 1], ['d', 'e', 'f', 2], ['g', 'h', 'i', 3]]
```